# In Java, when writing to a file with DataOutputStream, how do I define the Endian of the data being written?

Tags: java, io, endianness

I'm using `DataOutputStream` to write to a file, however I want to change the endian of the data.

This is how i'm writing the byte data to the file (it outputs in Little endian by default)

```
public void generateBinObjFile(String outputFile)
    try {
        // Create file

        DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        stream.writeShort(this.quantize(this.xComponents.get(index), //<-- Short is written in little Endian
                    this.min_x, this.max_x) - 32768);

        } // catch statements here
```

Is there a way i can define the Endian of how byte data is written in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not do this with `DataOutputStream`, which always uses big endian.

You *can* use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) on which you can call [`order()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) to influence how it reads and writes data.

You can use the `ByteBuffer` *either* to prepare a `byte[]` that you'll write with a classical `OutputStream` later on *or* go entirely to NIO and use any [`WritableByteChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html) for the writing

Comment: it says "cannot instantiate the type 'ByteBuffer' ".I'm using the new keyword to create an object of it, is there a different or more correct way of creating an instance of an object?

Comment: @deztructius: check the JavaDoc that I linked to, please.

Comment: You can use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(int size)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use: **com.google.common.io.LittleEndianDataOutputStream** from

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataOutputStream.html
or copy this class:
http://www.cafeaulait.org/books/javaio/ioexamples/07/LittleEndianOutputStream.java

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeShort%28int%29):

> Writes a short to the underlying output stream as two bytes, high byte first.

All the "multi-byte" methods work like that.
If you need it the other way around, you need to write bytes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

all the given answers are right. You can, however, take the source of DataOutputStream, paste it into a new class, and reverse the order of bytes in the various writeShort, writeLong etc.. (or at least in the ones you need). It is not such a difficult work.

Obviously you cannot then use it to communicate with a DataInputStream on the other side, but I suppose you need to write to a file or socket with a C program on the other side, so you'll not need a DataInputStream.

Answer (score -1):

It outputs the data in a fashion that is readable by DataInputStream.

If you have to worry about the endianness, you should not be using a Data*Stream.