# Select file encoding in OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, file-io

I am using the JDK 1.7 on Linux server. I have installed apache 6.0.35 and use the code

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(os,"Unicode");
```

to write a file in unicode format.

But the file is getting generated in unicode big endian format. How do I select a different output format?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024039/in-java-when-writing-to-a-file-with-dataoutputstream-how-do-i-define-the-endia

Answer (score 3):

'Unicode' isn't a single format, but specifies encodings like UTF-16 (big and little-endian) and UTF-8.

You probably want something specific like `UTF-16LE` rather than `Unicode`. Have a look at the list in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html

Comment: Note: it is Charset.UTF_16LE or "UTF-16LE"

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks for the correction. The underscore literal version works too for me; I guess it's an alias.

Comment: Sorry, it is StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE. :]

Comment: the generated file i have to commit to live scheduler which only accepts unicode format. In the old server the above code is running fine . in the new server only this problem is comming.   do i need to install X11R6

Comment: Is UTF-16BE a literal pass-thru mapping? i.e. if I am trying to OuterputStreamWriter.write binary data in a char [] will it pass it through without changing anything?

Comment: @Michael no. One of the 8-bit mappings might work (non-unicode), but why are you using a Writer to write binary data?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Unicode or UTF-16 it will be big endian by default.  If you don't specify endianess, Java assumed big endian as a rule.  If you want little endian you need to specify it with `"UTF-16LE"` or `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`

From java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

```
public static final Charset UTF_16LE = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: i have tried this also , the generated file is in in ANSI format.  The application in running under linux sever. do i need to install X11R6 .

Answer (score 0):

The Java charset name "UTF-16" means UTF-16 with big endian.
Try something like this little endian format:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),"UTF-16LE"));
```